# How can add a "Collapse the Ribbon" button to a CMFCRibbonBar

Tags: mfc, mfc-feature-pack, cmfcribbonpanel

I'm using CMFCRibbonBar in an MFC based Application, I would like to add the ability to collapse the ribbon like you can in Office, does anyone know if this can be done?

[image: image of ribbon bar in office]

I would be quite happy if I it was only possible to implement the button in the menu bar like in explorer/mspaint

[image: windows 10 explorer view]

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to answer my own question, seems you just drop a CMFCRibbonButton above the ribbon bar, give it an id, then in the event handler call

```
m_wndRibbonBar.ToggleMimimizeState();
```

Now to determine how I can change the button image on toggling

Comment: *"Now to determine how I can change the button image on toggling"* - found any way?

Comment: The only way I found was to make my own button which inherits from CMFCRibbonButton, then overloaded the virtual void DrawImage(CDC *pDC,RibbonImageType, CRect rectImage) method, in that method I called m_pParentGroup->OnDrawImage() and at that point I switched the image index based on if the bar was up or down. hope that helps